# pow() behaviour different with Float and Double

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, double, pow

I'm facing a weird issue with the `pow()`. Please check the following function

```
 let r = 8.5/1200
 let n = ((5*12.0)+1)

 let pp = (pow(Float(1 + r), Float(n)))
 debugPrint(pp) // 1.53811562

 let pq = (pow((1 + r), n))
 debugPrint(pq) // 1.5381189771003985
```

Here `pow(Float, Float)` function return max. 8 fractional number for `Float` and `pow(Double , Double)` returns value with 16 fractional number for `Double`.

Why it is so could anyone explain it?

And is it possible to get upto 16 fractional number for `Float` value?

> Note: You can copy and paste it in playground to see result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Float` uses an [IEEE 754 four byte single precision number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats). 24 bits are assigned to the significand and 8 bits to the exponent. With 24 bits of precision, it can represent a little over 7 decimal digits of precision

`Double` - which is the default floating point format for Swift uses an IEEE double precision eight byte number. The significand uses 53 bits and the exponent 11 bits. With 53 bits of precision, it can represent just under 16 decimal digits of precision.

The reason why `pq` is printed with 16 digits is that by default the compiler has inferred the argument type to be `Double`.

> And is it possible to get upto 16 fractional number for Float value?

No. There aren't enough bits of precision.

Comment: `Float` only guarantees that numbers of six decimal digits will survive a round-trip conversion from decimal to `Float` and back to the same number of decimal digits. It fails for some numbers with seven decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

Please look up the difference between [Double and Float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Double is called double because it has double precision compared to float.

To get the same result in your calculation just cast Double to Float or vice versa, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place for providing and preserving answer to questions. Instructions to look up things elsewhere are not useful, nor polite. Additionally, the vagaries of how different programming languages format floating-point values for output vary and contribute to difficulties in understanding why certain outputs occur.

Answer (score 1):

In swift

Float − This is used to represent a **32-bit** floating-point number and numbers with smaller decimal points. For example, 3.12345678

Double − This is used to represent a **64-bit** floating-point number and used when floating-point values must be very large. For example, 3.123456789123456

That could be a reason for that

According to Apple Docs

> Double has a precision of at least 15 decimal digits, whereas the precision of Float can be as little as 6 decimal digits. The appropriate floating-point type to use depends on the nature and range of values you need to work with in your code. In situations where either type would be appropriate, Double is preferred

And 
No , **You can't have 16 fractional number for Float value.**

Comment: The values you provided in each example are exactly the same

Comment: @JohnSnow Thanks for point it out fixed and i loved your name GOT ! (i have used this name for quite long time)